# How to make my hyperlinks be in the right side and logo in the left side in navigation?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I don't understand what to do with my css code, in order to move my hyperlinks in navigation to right side.

HTML code:
[My HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVbxS.png)

CSS code:
[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q7rC.png)

I've tried using "float" and deleted flex-container, but i can't even text with logo, it looked like this:
[After using "float"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN7hP.png)

PS. Sorry for code screens(editor just didn't let me to post code here).

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide your debugging details in the form of a [repro]. Images are neither an acceptable nor suitable replacement. Besides that, copy & paste is faster then screenshooting. Also, it would be a good time to read into flexbox instead of missing float as a hack to align items. `float` is a property to float an element within flow text such as images in a newspaper. It is no tool to position items on the left or right side.

Comment: Code blocks have to be formatted properly. It's easiest to copy and paste, then highlight the code and press `Ctrl+K` or click on the `{}` Code Sample button at the top of the editor. It's best to include the code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and in a runnable [Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) by pressing `Ctrl+M` or the `<>` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the magic of flexbox, you can achieve this pretty easily:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  
  header nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/120">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Some URL</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Some URL</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Some URL</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
 </html>
```

By making the header-element a flex-container, all children act as elements of the flex-container and react on the flex-settings of their parent. So in this case, the image-element is one flex-element while the nav-element is the other. Now, when you use justify-content: space-between on two elements, they will try to reach the edges both ways (to the left and to the right), as the flex-container tries to put all available space between the elements. As there are only two elements to share the available space, the whole space goes between them, resulting in your desired navbar.

Comment: Thank you, it worked) Btw, why do we need second selector " header nav ul" ?

Comment: Perfect, you can mark my answer as solution then. :-) With the header nav ul we say, that we don't want the bullet points to appear and that there should be a gap between each li-element so that we have a nice spacing between the elements but not on the outside (i.e. to the right side, where the navigation should end). This is all optional, just for design purposes...

Comment: In case you meant why the "nav" in header nav ul, you don't have to select it like this, as header ul or just ul would also work. But I like to make things very clear to myself and there could be another ul in the header but not in the nav-element. In This case, just using header ul would affect both ul-elements and not just the one in the nav.

Comment: @bergersilvio While I agree you should make things clear, you should not overspecify elements for 2 main reasons. For one it raises the specificity weight and in general, you should aim to keep your specificity weight as low as possible. The other reason is, that it takes more processing resources and time. CSS will read selectors backward. It first will select then every single ul and check then if they are within a nav element. Then it checks if the nav element is within a header element. `nav ul` would be specific enough while being more performant.

Comment: Thanks for the deeper insight behind the scenes of CSS - didn't know about the backwards reading. I still prefer to be a little bit more specific (and taking the risk of getting more weight) to be able to use more generic elements without having to create new classes and such for every little thing. And in fact, in most my cases, using nav ul would not suffice, because there would be second and third tier navigations which all have ul-elements. But you are right, in this specific case, nav ul would work too (as I've already mentioned in my previous explanatory comment).